# Ereg_replace to preg_replace Lep

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-5.3, ereg-replace

How would I make these two previous ereg_replace expressions work with preg_match?

```
http://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*|
```

and

```
(^| |\n)(www([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*)
```

adding code from comment

```
preg_replace("http://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>"
```

Comment: which part is not working, so far i see its all compatible. maybe i am mistaken

Comment: So this should work then?
preg_replace("http://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $message);

Comment: update the question with the syntax hard to read

Comment: preg_replace("http://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>"

Answer (score 0):

Just add delimiter arround the regex:

```
http://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*
```

becomes

```
/http:\/\/([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_\/-])*/
```

or, better

```
~http://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*~
```

Same for the second one:

```
(^| |\n)(www([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*)
```

becomes:

```
~(^| |\n)(www([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*)~
```